# Cannot set login id when using flask admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, unique-constraint, flask-admin

I'm using flask admin to allow admins to perform CRUD operations. So when adding a new user the website should automatically generate and set the unique login id for that user. I'm trying to implement it using the custom view classes inheriting from ModelView  class provided by flask admin as in the following code:

```
    class UserAdmin(ModelView):
        <...>

        def generate_login_id(self):
            while True:
                login_id = randint(100000, 999999)
                existing_user = User.query.filter_by(login_id=login_id).first()
                if not existing_user:
                    return login_id
                
        def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
            if is_created:
                global password, login_id
                login_id = self.generate_login_id()
                password = secrets.token_hex(4)
    
                model.login_id = login_id
                model.password = password
```

As the result I get the following error on the webpage:

```
<...> NOT NULL constraint failed: user.login_id <...>
```

After testing for several times I noticed that if I output `User.query.filter_by(login_id=login_id)` in the generate function I get the query output as expected. But once I add .first() method I expect to at least get None as output but what's surprising is that I don't get any output at all.

So login id is not set properly. However if i simply use `model.login_id = randint(100000, 999999)` it does work perfectly (but i want to use the function that will guarantee the uniqueness of the login id by using a while loop). So please suggest solutions for this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my question. It was very simple: I should have used database queries in flask application context. So the correct code would be:

```
def generate_login_id(self):
        while True:
            login_id = randint(100000, 999999)
            with app.app_context():
                existing_user = User.query.filter_by(login_id=login_id).first()
                if not existing_user:
                    return login_id
```

I think that flask admin library handled this "outside of app context" error and therefore the code simply didn't run further and I didn't see any output.